# Colors to same type words in text area in java

Tags: java

I am building text editor application using swing and JFrame. I want to give color to all keywords,constants.exactly like some java editors do. How can i achive this ?
Please help me. Thnx in advance.

Comment: this question is way too broad and it appears that you've given no effort toward solving your own problem.

Answer (score 2):

Kindly try it first and then ask question.Blankly we cannot answer kindly post your code what you tried.

Any way i ll post the link which will give you some idea.

[Highlighting the java](http://codewall.blogspot.in/2011/01/syntax-highlighting-in-java.html)

Comment: Link is dead .....  .

Answer (score 1):

You can color the words with html the only thing you need to do is replace the needed string. For this you can use Strings replaceAll method:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Than search the replaceAll method.